# why is my code in python not giving me an output?

Tags: class, oop

This is not giving me an output and also not giving me an error i dont know whats wrong

I was just learning oop

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self , name , age) :
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def speak(self ):
        print('I am ' + self.name + ' and I am ' + self.age + 'years old.')

tim = Dog('Lily' , 3)
```

Comment: Because you never called `speak` ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to let the dog speak with adding a `.speak()` to your class instantiation.

```py
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self , name , age) :
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def speak(self ):
        print('I am %s and I am %d years old.' % (self.name, self.age))

tim = Dog('Lily' , 3).speak()
```